# Can Keras / TensorFlow automatic model download be avoided cleanly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

Keras / TensorFlow will automatically download the weights of a model, when instantiating like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras import applications
model = applications.DenseNet121()
```

But for production purposes, I need to avoid this behavior. How can I cleanly check if that model was already downloaded, so I can raise an exception rather than have it automatically download it? I could of course manually check for the presence of the file `~/.keras/models/{model_identifier}_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5`. But I would like to avoid a dirty solution like that.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you do not need to check whether the weights of the model already exists or not in your system since Keras does this for you. You can inspect the source code from the following link: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/data_utils.py

It is an easy exercise to prove that;

> Let's create the weight file ourselves and try to call **applications.DenseNet121()**

```
!touch ~/.keras/models/densenet121_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
```

---

```
from tensorflow.keras import applications
model = applications.DenseNet121()
```

> Output

```
A local file was found, but it seems to be incomplete or outdated because the auto file hash does not match the original value of 9d60b8095a5708f2dcce2bca79d332c7 so we will re-download the data.
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/densenet/densenet121_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
```

> Edit

```
import os
from tensorflow.keras.applications import DenseNet121

if ('densenet121_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5' in os.listdir('/root/.keras/models/')):
  model = DenseNet121(weights = '/root/.keras/models/densenet121_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
else:
  # Throw your exception
```

Comment: Ok, but I am talking about the case, where there is NO file for the model. And then it automatically downloads it. Which I do not want to happen. I want it to just throw an exception / use an API call to check for whether the file exists. If it does not, I would throw an exception myself. In any case, I want to avoid the automatic download.

Comment: Can you help me to understand better, clearly I cannot follow-up. You want to throw an exception if the weights does not exist and you don't want to download. It is confusing what you would like to achieve with that, let say it does not exist and you threw an exception and not downloaded, what then; use your own weight, check somewhere else? I cannot imagine a use case. Would the code in the edited section solves your problem?

Comment: The environment is one where downloading files is not allowed. Hence, I would then exit the program. This is a failsafe. The weights should have been downloaded in a prior step in the build pipeline and copied into the container that runs the keras model. But in case this failed in some way, I need to avoid the automatic download.

Comment: The code in the edited section is the dirty workaround that I mentioned in my question. I would prefer a clean API-based solution. My question is, hence, if there is such a clean API-based solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know there is no clean API solution for that.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway!